# Kernel automatically dies when loading large data from GCS to Cloud Datalab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I'm uploading a 2 GB file from GCS ( a .vec file containing words and their vector representation). I want to use this file with gensim ( I already installed the library). I'm using a n1-highmem-2 (2 vCPUs, 13 GB memory) VM. The notebook automatically shuts down and the kernel dies when trying to load the file.

Comment: Hi Yahya - did you find a solution to this?  I am finding the same thing - the datalab kernel keeps crashing

Comment: Hi, unfortunatly no. I stopped using datalab.

Comment: Sorry to hear about that. If you'll like to check back on this, you can try loading the data in batches.